# JQueryUi datepicker stop Reinit on mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events, datepicker

I use JQueryUI datepicker, display inline mode. On page load i fill events in my calendar. But when i click on it (on any place ), my events was removed, i think datepicker was reinit.
How can i prevent it.

```
$('table').mouseup(
function() {
    $('td').unbind('mousedown mousemove');
});
```

I try this 2 methods, but they did not help me.
Thanks for help.

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ firstDay: 1 });

<div class="main">
    <?php $this->renderPartial('_dashboard_menu'); ?>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                <div id="datepicker"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your datepicker code?

Comment: I add it in my question.

Comment: Share your complete HTML where you have those tables.

Comment: i share my html full code

Comment: where is that HTML code for table,tr,td? Your code is not complete. Please be more clear on the issue.

Comment: table generated by jquery ui datepicker widget http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

Comment: So, you want to change the background color of the dates when hovered? Is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need Javascript for this purpose. Use pure CSS for it.
The datepicker gets styles from jquery ui css file. So if you want custom styles for your datepicker , then you can modify it accordingly. Otherwise you can also use custom css separately by using "!important" after the style property. For eg:
The dates in datepicker is basically an anchor with class ".ui-state-default" inside td. 
So if you want to change the background color then:

```
.ui-state-default:hover {background:red!important;}
```

or

```
.ui-state-default.ui-state-hover {background:red;}
```

You should avoid "!important" wherever possible.

Here is the jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/1/

Comment: ssory my question not depend hover, i fill events in calendar, when i click on it all event removed, i think widget was reinit onclick, i try prevent it.  code part with hover and background-color was wrong.